# Computational Geometry journals

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry

What are good computational geometry journals? I'm also counting geometric modeling as part of computational geometry. Are there any good journals that are considered to be non-mainstream in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Computational Geometry: Theory and Applications](http://www.elsevier.com/locate/comgeo) and [International Journal of Computational Geometry and Applications](http://ejournals.wspc.com.sg/ijcga/ijcga.shtml) are the ones that focus on algorithms. For geometric modeling, there's [Computer Aided Design](http://www.elsevier.com/locate/cad), [Computer Aided Geometric Design](http://www.elsevier.com/locate/cagd), [Graphical Models](http://www.elsevier.com/locate/gmod).

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Discrete and Computational Geometry: http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/journal/454  If what you want is an excellent survey of materials related to discrete and computational geometry I also recommend this Handbook: http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/discrete.html  edited by Joseph O'Rourke and Jacob Eli Goodman.